# Failed building wheel for scikit-learn

Tags: python

I am getting the following error when installing skicit-learn on windows 11 for python 3.10 version.

ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Could you please help me? Thank you